# VBA - Find text string in a "Word-document" and return corresponding line(s) and page number

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am new to the forum and also only recently active in VBA programming. In my current project I would like to realise the following:

I have a text in Word as a default. I have divided the content of this text into categories with the help of a web application. When I had completely categorised the Word document it was possible for me to download a .csv file with the corresponding data ([see appended picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fu8R.png) ). When I opened the file in Excel, the following columns were given: "Document", "Category", "Category Title", "Marked Text" (label to the original categorised Word text). Since I want to use the categorisation as a later source reference, it is necessary to find the line and page number for each text passage. Since the categorised text parts can extend over several lines, it is necessary to specify all of these lines (or at least the range from the first to the last one). Reading the text passages iteratively from the .csv and later entering the line numbers in the document is no problem. I am more interested in the code in between the loop to find the "Marked Text" in the Word document and to output the corresponding line(s) and page numbers.

I tried to implement the following VBA-code:

```
Sub search_return_line()

Dim wordapp As New Word.Application
Dim word_doc As Word.Document
Dim word_doc_path As String
Dim search_text As String

wordapp.Visible = True

word_doc_path = "INSERT_WORD_DOC_PATH"
Set word_doc = wordapp.Documents.Open(word_doc_path)

With word_doc.Content.Find
    text = "An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure" 'text line of interest to find in word 
        .Execute FindText := search_text
        If .Found = True Then
            ' if text was found get the corresponding line number
            MsgBox "The text: '" & search_text & "' was found! Line: " & .Parent.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
        Else
            MsgBox "Text not found!"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The Find function is working, but "word_doc.Content.Find.Parent.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)" does only return the relative number of the first caracter to the current (relative) page. It would be great to get the absolut number refering to the whole document and the number of the last line corresponding to the categorised text, too.

I would also appreciate an explanation of the code from your answers to learn and improve my understanding.

I hope that is all the information necessary to understand the problem.
I would be very grateful for any feedback.

Many greetings
Konsti

Comment: While you can certainly do this in VBA, I wonder why you don't just use the Word index feature?

Comment: `appended picture` is missing. Why you try to read csv with Word? You can open csv as a text file with VBA.

Comment: See also https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/word/extract-sentences-with-a-specific-word-amp-page-number-from-word/m-p/3929049 which seems to be addressing a similar issue. If in the Word document, use the Index feature. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Index

Comment: Thank you all very much for your advice. Using the Windows index feature is probably not useful for my purpose. Again, basically, I have an interview that is in MS word. The information that the interviewee gives is categorised with the help of a web application and his statements are sorted according to the main topics. In order to be able to refer to this raw interview in the appendix of the actual report, the page and line numbers must be given. I wanted to do this using a loop procedure in VBA, as there are more than 10 categories and each category has over 100 entries.